# How to check how many files are there in a folder?

Tags: c++, windows, file

I would like to check how many files are there in the specified directory. For instance I would have a directory next to my .exe called `resources` and I would like to check how many of .txt files are located in it.

How this can be done in C++ in Windows?

Comment: 100% OS depedent. Mind you that there are systems that get programmed in C where no kind of filsystem even exist. If you call fopen on such a system you get linker error!

Comment: Tagged as Windows now, so it's going to be FindFirstFile(), FindNextFile() and FindClose() API calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the operating system.  On Windows, you would use [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate the directory contents, using an appropriate filter such as `"*.txt"`.  Don't foget to call [`FindClose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when you're done.

On Unix-based operating systems, you would use [`opendir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and [`readdir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) to enumerate the directory contents.  You'll have to filter the file names yourself.  Don't forget to call [`closedir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/closedir) when you're done.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use boost::filesystem. There's even a [sample program](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration) that has most of the work done for you.

Answer (score 0):

This MS Windows code lists all `.txt` files  in C:. To list all other files, change `strcpy(DirSpec, "c:\\*.txt")`   to `strcpy(DirSpec, "c:\\*")` .

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 
#include <windows.h> 
#define BUFSIZE MAX_PATH 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData; 
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE; 
    DWORD dwError; 
    LPSTR DirSpec;
    unsigned int nFiles=0;
    DirSpec = (LPSTR) malloc (BUFSIZE); 
    strcpy(DirSpec, "c:\\*.txt"); 

    printf ("Current directory : %s\n\n", DirSpec); 

    hFind = FindFirstFile(DirSpec, &FindFileData); 
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    { 
        printf ("incorrect Handle : %u.\n", GetLastError()); 
        return (-1); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        printf ("%s\n", FindFileData.cFileName); 


        while ( FindNextFile (hFind, &FindFileData) != 0) 
        { 
             nFiles++;
             printf ("%s\n", FindFileData.cFileName); 
        } 

        dwError = GetLastError(); 
        FindClose(hFind); 

        printf ("\n %d files found.\n\n", nFiles); 

        if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) 
        { 
             printf ("FindNextFile Error.\n", dwError); 
             return (-1); 
        } 
    } 
    free(DirSpec); 
   return (0); 
}
```